# Three-dimensional array processing

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, deep-learning

I want to turn

```
arr = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]], [[2,2,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]], [[3,3,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
```

into

```
arr = np.array([[[1,2,3],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]], [[2,2,2],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]], [[3,3,3],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
```

Below is the code:

```
a = 0
b = 0
NewArr = []
while a < 3:
    c = arr[a, :, :]
    d = arr[a]
    print(d)
    if c[1, 2] == 6:
         c = np.delete(c, [1], axis=0)
    a += 1
    b += 1

    c = np.concatenate((d, c), axis=1)

    print(c)
```

But after deleting the line containing the number 6, I cannot stitch the array together，Can someone help me?
thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `cannot stitch the array together` - that's not very clear.  If you get an error in the `concatenate` expression, tell us what it is.  I suspect that with the `delete` you are changing the shape of `c` so it is no longer compatible with the shape of `d` - at least not for the chosen axis.  Do you understand how shapes must match to use `concatenate`?

Comment: Your sample `arr` doesn't contain a `6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a more automatic way of processing your input data, here is an answer using numpy functions :

```
arr[np.newaxis,~np.any(arr==6,axis=2)].reshape((3,-1,3))
```

np.any(arr==6,axis=2) outputs an array which has True at rows which contain the value 6. We take the inverse of those booleans since we want to remove those rows. The solution is then used as an index selection in arr, with a np.newaxis because the output of np.any had one axis less than the original array.

Finally, the output is reshaped into a 3,x,3 array, where x will depend on the number of rows which were removed (hence the -1 in reshape)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the input / output you provide, a simpler solution would be to just use index selection and slices:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]], [[2,2,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]], [[3,3,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
print("arr=")
print(arr)

expected_result = np.array([[[1,2,3],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]], [[2,2,2],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]], [[3,3,3],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])

# select indices 0, 2 and 3 from dimension 2
a = np.copy(arr[:,[0,2,3],:])
print("a=")
print(a)

print(np.array_equal(a, expected_result))
```

Output:

```
arr=
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]
  [10 11 12]]

 [[ 2  2  2]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]
  [10 11 12]]

 [[ 3  3  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]
  [10 11 12]]]
a=
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 7  8  9]
  [10 11 12]]

 [[ 2  2  2]
  [ 7  8  9]
  [10 11 12]]

 [[ 3  3  3]
  [ 7  8  9]
  [10 11 12]]]
True
```

Comment: I Think the OP was looking for an answer where the index of the rows to delete are not known. Rather, he is looking to delete rows which contain a specific numeric value (6 in this example).